# jsf upload file upload immediately

Tags: file, jsf, input, submit

I have a little problem and I wonder is it possible to resolve it in JSF 2.2.3
I use relatively new inputFile tag and it works ok:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h:inputFile id="auctionImage" value="#{auctionBean.image}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Add">
                        <f:ajax execute="auctionImage" render="images"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                    <h:panelGroup id="images">
                        <ui:repeat value="#{auctionBean.productImages}" var="oneImage">
                            <h:graphicImage value="/image/#{oneImage.url}" width="200" height="171" />
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>
```

I want to show every submitted img on the website and have one main sumbit button to submit them all at once. It works ok. 
The problem is I have three buttons to browse for image, to submit image and to submit all images. Is it possible to submit it after clicking OK in explorator window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after day of trying with javascript i realized that it's very simple to achieve by just an ajax tag.

```
            <h:form class="imageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="browseButton"><span class="browseString">BROWSE...</span>
                    <h:inputFile id="auctionImage" value="#{auctionBean.image}"> 
                        <f:ajax execute="auctionImage" render=":mainForm:repeatImages"/>
                    </h:inputFile>
                </div>
            </h:form>
```

Yes, that's it.

PS I used wrapper div and opacity trick for button to change standard html 5 appearance.